# Merging tables by two id simultaneously in R

Tags: r, join, merge

I have 3 datasets

```
df1 has two column with id
df2 has one column with id
df3 has one column with id


df1=structure(list(id1.df1 = c(1L, 3L, 5L), id2.df1 = 4:6, ids = c(0.7, 
0.8, 0.9)), .Names = c("id1.df1", "id2.df1", "ids"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2=structure(list(id1.df2 = c(1L, 3L, 5L), x3 = c(46L, 6546L, 65L
)), .Names = c("id1.df2", "x3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df3=structure(list(id2.df3 = c(2L, 4L, 5L), x4 = c(5467L, 78L, 654L
)), .Names = c("id2.df3", "x4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I need to merge these 3 datasets so, that the query would return
strings that match id1 and id2 from the first dataset with id1 from the second and id2 from the third dataset.

On output i expect

```
id1-df1 id1-df2 ids id2-df1 x3  id2-df3 x4
    1   4        0,7    1   46     4    78
    3   5        0,8    3   6546   5    654
    5   6        0,9    5   65     6    5467
```

I.E, 1 and 4 id of the first dataset are merged to the 1 id of the second dataset and the 4 id of the third dataset, respectively.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

First, I think there is an error in your statement giving the data for df3. I think that you wanted `id2.df3 = c(6L, 4L, 5L)`.   Using that data, you can do this using merge twice.

```
merge(merge(df1, df2, by.x = 'id1.df1', by.y = 'id1.df2'),
  df3, by.x = 'id2.df1', by.y = 'id2.df3')
  id2.df1 id1.df1 ids   x3   x4
1       4       1 0.7   46   78
2       5       3 0.8 6546  654
3       6       5 0.9   65 5467
```

This only contains the id1 and id2 columns once, not twice like your proposed answer, but those are completely redundant.  You could add extra copies if you want.